# How to get selected value from ui-selects in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm adding ui-selects with ng-repeat but i don't know how to get value from each ui-select separately in controller. I want to get the selected item value in controller for use as parameters to send a $http request.

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeats">
   <p>Selected: {{pattern.selected.name}}</p>
   <ui-select ng-model="repeat.id">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an pattern...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="pattern in data_pattern_newspapers track by $index">
  <div ng-bind-html="pattern.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

I want doing somethings as below in my controller:

```
alert($scope.repeat.id.selected)
```

How can i access to model of each ui-select in my controller?

My
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3PuYKADoG1GzPotr9QR?p=preview)

Please some body help me. thanks!

Comment: your `ng-model` on `repeat.id` is changing the `id` value from it's initial value to the value of whatever you select in the dropdown.  that may or may not be what you want; it probably isn't, since your selects are binding an object:  http://plnkr.co/edit/sOrXVNiUQaj5HO3TKJyH?p=preview

Comment: in order to make it easier for others to suggest alternatives, you may want to explain what you are planning on using the values for.

Comment: @Claies I want to get the selected item value in controller for use as parameters to send a $http request. So what should i do in controller for get the this selected item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html utilise the `$index` property of ngRepeat to create a unique model for each `ui-select`, and pass `$index` into the ngChange function:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selections[$index]" ng-change="selectionChanged($index)">
```

In your controller initialise an array to hold the selected values, and add the above function receiving the `$index` to reference this array:

```
$scope.selections = [];

$scope.selectionChanged = function(idx) {
  console.log(idx, $scope.selections[idx]);
};
```

Now `$scope.selections` is an array of their selections as they make them.

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NSK3UmelATopV0Juw8BV?p=preview

Comment: Note that `ngChange` function is not required - you can just reference `$scope.selections` whenever you want, but I presume you're likely looking to take some sort of action when their selection changes. The key however is to use $index: `ng-model="selections[$index]"`

Comment: Yes, exactly. worked perfectly. thanks! @K Scandrett